# Gmail SMTP server Fails on send using PHPMailer

Tags: php, laravel, smtp, gmail

i created this PHP Class for sending emails

```
    class Mailbox{

    private $mail; 

    public function initialize(){
        $this->mail = new PHPMailer;
        $this->mail->Mailer = "smtp.gmail.com"; 
        $this->mail->Host = "mail.****.***.*g"; 
        $this->mail->Port = 587; 
        $this->mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
        $this->mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication 
        $this->mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";

        $this->mail->Username = '****@******.com';                

        $this->mail->Password = '67******!';                  // SMTP password                              
        $this->mail->SetFrom('****@******.com', 'Federal Admin');           

    }

    public function addSubject($sub='***** testing mail...'){
        $this->mail->Subject  = $sub;
        $this->mail->AltBody  = "...just a sample message"; 
    }

    public function addMessage($msg){
        $this->mail->MsgHTML($msg);
    }

    public function addAddress($addr){
        foreach($addr as $ad){
            $this->mail->AddAddress($ad[0], $ad[1]);
        }
    }   
    public function send(){
        if(!$this->mail->Send()) {
           return "Mailer Error: mail not sent.." . $this->mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
           return true;
        }
    }

}
```

and this is my implementation in my code...

```
$ar = array(
    ['****r@k**g.gov', 'Recruit'],
    ['an***i@aol.com','Officer'],
    ['***iii@gmail.com','Secretary']
);


$message = $msg->render(); //renders a htmlview


$m = new Mailbox;
$m->initialize();
$m->addSubject('Reports from my store Armory');
$m->addMessage($message);
$m->addAddress($ar);

if($m->send()){
    echo 'messsage sent successfully';
}else{
    echo 'error sending message';
}
```

it was working three days ago, tuesday precisely, the image below is the output from my aol mail, but just of recent, since wednesday, it hasnt been functioning properly. i didn't touch or change anything, i have been lost and going round in circles. please i need help. Does anyone know if GMail is Having any issues  or is anyone experiencing the same issue as me..

[image: Email Response 3 days ago...]
Please i need help if anyone has solved this issue, my guess is that Gmail is having issues, i have changed the allow unsecured apps settings and yet i still keep getting these errors.

Comment: Are you using your own smtp server or are you attempting to use googles smtp server?

Comment: i'm attempting to use google, i already did, and it worked earlier, and all of a sudden it stopped... i dont know why

Comment: Perhaps try changing the smtp server to smtp.google.com ?

Comment: Just change your port number to 465. Gmail using ssl smtp port number is 465. 587 is tls port

Comment: @JasonBassett, i did that already, lemme correct it, it was smtp.google.com, and like i said it was working earlier, but stopped recently, i dont know what went rong.

Answer (score 1):

- turn On Allow less secure apps.
  and change:

`$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tsl';// Enable TLS encryption,`ssl`also accepted
 $mail->Port = 587;`

check this!
http://www.tutsplanet.com/send-email-using-smtp-server-phpmailer-997/